# Accidentally quit while using JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter

I use jmeter to test api. After it runs sometime, i press stop button then it quit unexpectedly. Who can help me?

os: macOs
jmeter version: 5.3

Comment: See and post here the error in jmeter.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all don't use GUI for test execution, JMeter GUI is only for tests development and debugging, when it comes to running tests [you should launch JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/test.jmx -l /path/to/result.jtl
   ```

   if you need to terminate the test before it ends naturally - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or use [stoptest.sh](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/stoptest.sh) or [shutdown.sh](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/bin/shutdown.sh) script
2. Normally if something goes wrong there should be some information in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
3. If there is nothing in jmeter.log file check if there are any .[hprof files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html) in the folder where you launch JMeter from
4. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), for example the very first one suggests [using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) which is [JMeter 5.4.1 as of now](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help i will look on with this.